# error as Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void writeStringField(String, Object) from the type System.JSONGenerator

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger CM_FieldMappingTrigger on Campaign (before update) {
//dynamically get the fields from the field set and then use the same for comparison in the trigger.
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.fields.getMap();//Get the schema field map to get all the fields 
set<String> allCampaignFieldList = new set<String>(); //Get all the fields of campaign object
allCampaignFieldList.addAll(schemaFieldMap.keySet());
JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);  

    for(Campaign a: trigger.new){
    set<String> changedFieldSet  = new Set<String>();
    for(string s: allCampaignFieldList){
        if(a.get(s) != trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).get(s)){
            changedFieldSet.add(s);//adding fields whose value changed
            system.debug('changedFieldSet'+changedFieldSet);
        }
    }
    generator.writeStartObject();                            
    generator.writeObjectField('show details', allCampaignFieldList);
    if(changedFieldSet.size()>0){
        for(string fc:changedFieldSet){
          String jsonString = generator.getAsString(); 
           a.Parent_Field_Tracking__c=jsonString; 
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `writeStringField` method in your code posted?

Comment: I cant find writeStringField in your code? Are you trying to add list allCampaignFieldList isntead?

Comment: Yup, no `writeStringField()` there...

Comment: @Priyan, This looks like http://xyproblem.info/ , can you describe what you want to do?

Comment: yap can you help me with writeStringField for above code

Comment: i have no idea how can we use it

Comment: i want to map old and new value upon update into a filed Parent_Field_Tracking__c in json format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this more difficult than you need to. You don't need `JSONGenerator` at all.

Instead, build the data structure that you want stored, and then serialize that directly to JSON. For example, you could do this:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> changeFieldData = new List<Map<String, String>>();

    if(a.get(s) != trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).get(s)){
        changeFieldData.add(
            new Map<String, String>{
                'NewValue' => a.get(s),
                'OldValue' => trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).get(s),
                'FieldName' => s
            }
        );
    }
```

if what you want stored is a list of objects, where each object has a key for the new value, the old value, and the field name.

Then just do

```
a.Parent_Field_Tracking__c = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{ 'show details' => changeFieldData });
```

to serialize the data structure into JSON.

As a side note, Salesforce field history tracking is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: +1 Pretty much what I was about to say. JSONGenerator is only really for portability rather than having any real use for native Apex.